# what is the value of angle $\alpha$ in the given figure?

Tags: geometry

For reference: $\overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{MN} = 80^o, \overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{NC} = 120^o.$

[image]

My progress:

$ \alpha =  \frac{\overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{MN}- \overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{MH} }{2}=\frac{80- \overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{MH} }{2} \\40 =  \frac{\overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{CN}- \overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{HB} }{2} =\frac{120- \overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{HB}}{2}\implies  \overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{HB}=40^o\\\overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{GB}=80^o\\\overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{IG}=2\alpha$

[image]

missing a detail to finish...

original figure
[image]

Comment: If MC is diameter then $MN=60^o$.

Comment: The half-circle seems to have no role in the question. Are you sure the text is correct?

Comment: @Intelligentipauca oh, that is true. Without it the problem becomes more clear.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca  Grateful for the effort... I think there must be an auxiliary construction because this question is from a Peruvian book and they don't use trigonometry... if it was possible to find the arc $\overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{MH}$, the problem was solved

Comment: But the half-circle plays no role in this problem: I think there is some error in the text. Is the given figure identical to the one above?

Comment: @Intelligentipauca..yes..I posted the original image...in geogebra it is possible to draw and the angle is really 18 degrees

Comment: The angle is NOT 18°: as I showed in my answer an exact construction gives $x=18.04214°$ up to five decimal figures.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca yes.but sometimes the the answers are approximate

Comment: @Intelligentipauca ..the $\overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{MH}$ should be worth approximately $44^\circ$

Comment: I've just seen [this question of yours](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4235401/what-is-the-measure-of-the-measuredangle-ead-where-e-is-outside-the-square), where in fact an approximate answer is given. But that problem cannot be solved without trigonometry.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca  
In the problem you mentioned, a remarkable triangle was used...they actually use this device...but if there is no way to solve it by geometry there are no problems...maybe some additional information was missing...because in the whole book they don't use it trigonometry,,, grateful

Answer (score 1):

The figure can be constructed with GeoGebra: given $AB$, from
$\angle CBN=60°$ one can construct point $N$;
from $\angle AMN=140°$ and $\angle NBM=40°$ we can then find $M$, as the intersection of a circle and a half-line.

As you can see below, we have $\alpha\approx 18.04214°$, a result which seems hard to obtain without trigonometry.

[image]

EDIT.

Let $AB=1$. From the sine rule applied to triangle $ABN$ we get:
$$
AN={\sin60°\over\sin20°},\quad
BN={\sin40°\over\sin20°}.
$$
From the sine rule applied to triangle $AMN$ we also get:
$$
MN=AN{\sin\alpha\over\sin140°}={\sin60°\sin\alpha\over\sin20°\sin40°}.
$$
Note that $\angle BMN=80°+\alpha$. Hence, from the sine rule applied to triangle $BMN$ we also get:
$$
MN=BN{\sin 40°\over\sin(80°+\alpha)}={\sin^240°\over\sin20°\sin(80°+\alpha)}.
$$
Equating these two expressions for $MN$ we then obtain an equation for $\alpha$, which can be written as:
$$
\sin60°\sin\alpha\sin(80°+\alpha)=\sin^340°.
$$
This leads to a quadratic equation for $\tan\alpha$, which can be solved to:
$$
\tan\alpha=\frac{\sqrt{-16 \sin ^640°+8 \sqrt{3} \sin10° \sin ^340°
+3 \cos ^210°}-\sqrt{3} \cos10°}{2 \left(\sqrt{3}
\sin10°-2 \sin ^340°\right)}.
$$
Mathematica simplifies that to:
$$
\tan\alpha=\frac{\csc10° \left(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{10\sin10°
+4 \cos20°-3}\right)}{2 (2 \sin10°+1)}
$$
and you can check that this corresponds to the value of $\alpha$ given above.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Hints: Through angle chasing find the measures show in the figure.I think the measure of radius of circles help us to calculate $\alpha$:

$\\alpha= 80\times \frac{R_O=ON=51}{R_P=DP=110}\approx 36^o$

The the measure of radius $R_j\approx54$

Comment: How do we know that $\overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{AN} = 80^\circ$?

Comment: it is the mirror of arc ND about  NP (NP is the symmetry axis of arcs ND and NA).

Comment: Thanks for help but I couldn't understand its distribution well ..

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is a construction with circles and lines and an angle to be picked out of it. Equations are set up and $\alpha$  is obtained analytically in case a higher accuracy is needed.

Anyway the following construction in `Geogebra`  makes a circle segment containing $40^{\circ}$ cutting the tangent at M ..

[image]

giving $ \angle NAM = \alpha \approx 18.04^{\circ} $