# What is the measurement of the angle $x$ indicated in the figure below.?

Tags: geometry

For reference: Calculate "$x$"if , $A, B$ and $C$ are points of tangency. $\overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{AC}=80^o$

[image]

My progress:

I confess that I didn't have many ideas in this...only:

$\measuredangle AQC = \measuredangle ARC = 40^o$

[image]

Comment: The original diagram is not clear. I suppose it is intended that the lower side of the angle $x$ should pass through $C$, because otherwise I cannot see how the problem has sufficient constraints to determine an answer, but in the figure the point of tangency seems to be below that line.

Comment: @ACB..I noticed the error in my drawing now.I'll fix it and as soon as I'm done I'll post it. These designs with multiple circles are not easy to make in geogebra. (The problem with these Peruvian exercises is that the drawings are often not well done and leave doubts. For reference the solution given is $ x = 95^o$ )

Comment: @ACB  I believe it's right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From quadrilateral $MBNO$ you get:
$$
\overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{AB}+\overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{CE}=360°-90°-80°=190°.
$$
And from triangle $BFG$:
$$
x={1\over2}\overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{AB}+
{1\over2}\overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{CE}=95°.
$$

[image]

Comment: excellent, thank you very much...Could you check the question below...maybe there is an exit not yet seen?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4242039/what-is-the-value-of-angle-alpha-in-the-given-figure

Comment: very nice answer! somehow missed this question earlier. btw your diagram looks so much better than what I manage to draw using GeoGebra :) the line thickness and colors etc. Are you using GeoGebra or another tool? any place where I can learn to use GeoGebra better?

Comment: @MathLover I must confess I always use GeoGebra 4 to draw 2-D figures, because the default style of lines and point is much better, as you noted. Anyway, you can change line width and point size in GeoGebra 5, to obtain almost the same result.